# Why is $string from included file not presented where it should be?

Tags: php, html, include

I hope its not duplicate or already been answered because I cant find nothing similar on SO.
I have included file: include 'data/news.php';

```
 <?php
$news = '

<div class="news_title">News Title</div>
<div class="news_date">Newsdate</div>
<div class="news_content">News content</div>

';

echo $news;

?>
```

In index file I try to show $news like this:

```
<div class="rightbox"><div class="h1title">Novice</div>
<?php $news ?>
</div>
```

Class "rightbox" is floated to the right side, but my $news is displayed right after menu content, its not in < div class =" rightbox " > "here" < /div > as I thought it should be (it makes no sense -> it should be in rightbox div but its not ?? 
Here's a screenshot of firebug:

http://i43.tinypic.com/kz505.png

I cant find any explanation on this so any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: You're `echo`ing $news inside the file you're including. That will output it when you include the file. Additionally, in your `<?php $news ?>` - that's not going to output anything; you'd need `<?php echo $news ?>` to print it out.

Comment: Thanx, I dont know why is echo in news.php file. Thank you very much, you saved me a lot of time :)

Comment: write an answer so I can award you ?

Comment: That's quite alright - feel free to accept Neal's answer, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo` <-- you need to `echo` the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Simply writing the variable name in the php does nothing. You need to print the contents of the variable to the page.

Two possible ways of doing this are: 
1.`echo`

```
echo $news;
```

2. `print`

```
print $news;
```

They both to the same thing.